# Separation of variables - when/why should the boundary data be homogeneous?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have some PDE defined on some domain prescribed with some boundary conditions. So far I have learned that if the domain is taken to be $\mathbb{R}^n$ then the boundary conditions must be homogeneous. I postulate that this has to do with taking linear combinations of solutions, but a confirmation on this would be nice or an explanation if my conjecture is incorrect.

What I am interested in is why this requirement of homogeneous boundary conditions is not necessary when working in other coordinate systems, namely polar domains. In what systems is this requirement necessary, and why?

Comment: Where did you find that in spherical coordinates your Dirichlet BCs do not have to be homogeneous?

Comment: @DanDoe Sorry I should have been more specific, but for example if you are sovling Laplace's equation on an annulus, on the disk, or on the exterior of a disk, your boundary conditions need not be zero. That is the motivation behind my question.